# Distance from a point to a set is attained on the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $X \in \mathbb R^n \backslash E^o $, where $E^o$ is the interior of $E$. Show that $dist(X,E)= dist(X, \partial E)$, where $\partial E$ denotes the boundary of $E$ and $dist(X,E)= inf_{y \in E } ||x-y||$.

Comment: **Hint:** Show that for any point $y\in E$, there is a point $z\in \partial E$ such that $d(y,x)\ge d(z,x)$.

Comment: Could you add a little more detail. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y\in E$ and $x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus E°$. We have a line segment $[y,x]=\{tx+(1-t)y\mid 0\le t\le1\}$, the points between $y$ and $x$. Since the map $p:[0,1]\to[y,x],\ t\mapsto tx+(1-t)y$ is continuous, $p^{-1}\left(\overline E\right)$ is closed, so there is a largest point $m$ in $p^{-1}\left(\overline E\right)$. Can you show that

- $p(m)$ is in $\partial E$
- $d(p(m),x)\le d(y,x)$

and deduce that $d(x,\partial E)\le d(x,E)$ ?

Comment: @ Stefan many thanks for your answer.