# $\delta$ neighborhood of a set description by its boundary

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

I want to know whether a mild condition can ensure that
$$K^\delta= K\cup (\partial K)^{\delta}$$
for a compact set $K\subseteq X$ in a metric space $X$, where $A^\delta= \cup_{a\in A}B(a,\delta)$ is the $\delta$-neighborhood of a set $A$.

For example, if $K$ is the countable union of disjoint convex sets $\{ K_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$, then I'm pretty sure $K_n^\delta=K_n \cup (\partial K_n)^{\delta}$ and $K^\delta= \cup_{n=1}^\infty K_n^\delta$. This is definitely the case when $X=\mathbb{R}$, but I was wondering whether this necessarily is true for $X=\mathbb{R}^d$ or even when $X$ is just a locally convex metric space?

The problem that I'm having, is that for every $x\in K^\delta \setminus K$ I want to show that there is a $k\in \partial K$ such that $d(x,k)<\delta$. By definition of $K^\epsilon$, there exists a $k'\in K$ such that $d(x,k')<\delta$. I want to show that there must be a $k\in \partial K$ satisfying $d(x,k)\leq d(x,k')$. This is only problematic when $k'\in \text{int}(K)$, but I am not sure how to obtain such a $k$ from $k'$.

I thought that maybe I can conclude this $k$ from a [Hahn Banach seperation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Geometric_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_(the_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_separation_theorems)). By taking a seperating functional for $x$ and a convex neighborhood $N$ of $k'$ intersected with $K$, that $\sup f[N]$ would have to be obtained on $\partial K$.

I am not sure if this intuition should be true or whether I need more assumptions on $X$. I would appreciate any input to solve this problem. I also suspect that the original equality should hold for other metric spaces $X$, and would gladly listen to any input on that direction.

Comment: Maybe I'm being naive. Do you have any counterexamples? It feels as if it is something that should be "automatically" true

Comment: @FShrike I don't have a counter example right now, but maybe because I'm thinking mostly of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I also thought it should automatically true, but I thought that perhaps some pathological space might be why I can't show this statement.

Comment: The distance of a point from a compact set is always attained on the boundary of the latter

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti It's exactly that sort of statement that I'm not sure how to prove generally. Can you refer me to a proof of that?

Comment: See here for example for $\Bbb R^n$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153148/distance-from-a-point-to-a-set-is-attained-on-the-boundary (some assumption on the metric space is needed, think about $([-1,1]\times\{0\})\cup\{(0,1)\}$ with the metric induced from the plane)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti So the statement you mean is for the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case? Because the $p$ there is exactly a functional separating a set from a point. I also don't understand why your counter example is a problem, as it is equal to its boundary.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur what is the distance between $(0,1)$ and $[-1/2,1/2]\times\{0\}$? Note that the latter isn't equal to its boundary, it has nonempty interior in the subspace topology!

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I'm not sure where the two sets in the example you wrote live, but I think you mean that in the example the distance is not attained. I think this sort of problem is avoided if the underlying space is complete.

Comment: The two sets live in the space from my previous comment (which is complete), the distance is attained (between $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$) but not on the boundary of $[-1/2,1/2]$

Comment: Again, take those two sets as a topological space with the induced topology from $\Bbb R^2$, so that the interval now has nonempty interior

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I think I finally see what you mean. Thanks and sorry for the hassle.